# Прооблема с кодировкой при чтении данных из clickhouse

Tags: java, jdbc, кодировка, clickhouse

Читаю данные из СУБД `clickhouse`. Смысл в том, что база (или драйвер) в случае пустого значения подставляет не привычную пустую строку, а набор непонятных симоволов. `Java` понимает это как полноценную строку в следствии чего возникают проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Похожее происходит и если строка меньше заданной. Как я могу в программе опознать эти непонятные символы, для дальнейшего удаления ?

Comment: Это официальный JDBC-драйвер?

Comment: @etki, да, правда версии 0.1.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, квадратик - это `char`, который равен 0. Избавился от него прогоном в стриме следующего кода:

```
map(id -> id.replace(new String(new char[]{0}), ""))
```

Решения лучше пока не нашел.